# etcd fatal error: failed to reserve page summary memory

Tags: go, etcd, patroni

when i try to run `etcd` from user account (Total RAM: 8GB, virtual memory of 1GB) in a 64 bit Linux environment (limited resources), I am getting the following error:

```
fatal error: failed to reserve page summary memory

runtime stack:
runtime.throw(
{0x108df50?, 0x7fffd8aa6850?}
)
/usr/local/go/src/runtime/panic.go:1047 +0x5d fp=0x7fffd8aa6800 sp=0x7fffd8aa67d0 pc=0x437edd
runtime.(*pageAlloc).sysInit(0x194f2f0)
/usr/local/go/src/runtime/mpagealloc_64bit.go:82 +0x195 fp=0x7fffd8aa6888 sp=0x7fffd8aa6800 pc=0x42c9b5
runtime.(*pageAlloc).init(0x194f2f0, 0x194f2e0, 0x0?)
/usr/local/go/src/runtime/mpagealloc.go:324 +0x70 fp=0x7fffd8aa68b0 sp=0x7fffd8aa6888 pc=0x42a610
runtime.(*mheap).init(0x194f2e0)
/usr/local/go/src/runtime/mheap.go:721 +0x13f fp=0x7fffd8aa68e8 sp=0x7fffd8aa68b0 pc=0x427a3f
runtime.mallocinit()
/usr/local/go/src/runtime/malloc.go:407 +0xb2 fp=0x7fffd8aa6910 sp=0x7fffd8aa68e8 pc=0x40c4f2
runtime.schedinit()
/usr/local/go/src/runtime/proc.go:693 +0xab fp=0x7fffd8aa6970 sp=0x7fffd8aa6910 pc=0x43b8ab
runtime.rt0_go()
/usr/local/go/src/runtime/asm_amd64.s:345 +0x11c fp=0x7fffd8aa6978 sp=0x7fffd8aa6970 pc=0x469c3c
```

But the same works fine from root account.

Can someone please support?

I was expecting this should give same output from root and user account. This seems like a virtual memory issue to me.

Answer (score 0):

As your request isn't very clear, I'm going to share with you a working piece of code that can successfully interact with etcd:

```golang
package main

import (
    "context"
    "fmt"
    "time"

    clientv3 "go.etcd.io/etcd/client/v3"
)

func main() {
    cli, err := clientv3.New(clientv3.Config{
        Endpoints:   []string{"localhost:2379"},
        DialTimeout: 5 * time.Second,
    })
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    defer cli.Close()

    // insert values
    res, err := cli.Put(context.Background(), "key1", "val1")
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    fmt.Printf("revision: %q\n", res.Header.Revision)

    // delete all keys
    defer cli.Delete(context.Background(), "key", clientv3.WithPrefix())

    // get object from etcd
    key, err := cli.Get(context.Background(), "key1")
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    fmt.Printf("key: %q\tvalue: %q\n", key.Kvs[0].Key, key.Kvs[0].Value)
}
```

This code assumes that you've got a running instance of ETCD that listens on port `2379` for incoming requests. I run ETCD with Docker with the following script:
`docker run -d -p 2379:2379 -p 2380:2380 --env ALLOW_NONE_AUTHENTICATION=yes --env ETCD_ADVERTISE_CLIENT_URLS=http://etcd-server:2379 bitnami/etcd:latest`

Hope this helps in clarifying a little bit!

Comment: thank you for the information. The above GO code you shared can help in communicating with etcd. The issue I am facing is slightly different. Not able to start etcd instance from user account and gives log as mentioned above

Comment: okay, got it! Can you share what you tried? The commands you used and so on?

Comment: I installed etcd in local machine Docker container (x86_64 bit). 
apt-get update
apt install etcd

This works as expected. 
I copied the binary etcd to the target system which has 8GB memory. With root login I am able to execute etcd properly

When I change to a user account and try to execute, I am getting the following error.
 
$ ./etcd
fatal error: failed to reserve page summary memory

Comment: In your container, did you set the role, user, and permissions you need for running etcd with a non-root user? I'm asking this because I was able to accomplish what you need by building directly within the container with a newly created user

Comment: thanks for the input. yes. i created a user account and tested in the container. It works well. sree@a7bd3c51a4a1:/usr/bin$ ./etcd
2022-11-24 14:38:04.511968 I | etcdmain: etcd Version: 3.2.17                      
  issue is observed only when etcd executable is copied to target system

Comment: As I'm not able to repro your issue, can you share the exact steps that take you to that error? Commands, Dockerfiles, everything so I can better help you, thanks!

Comment: thank you for your support. I am not sure whether you can reproduce the issue at your end. the reason is we are installing this in a target embedded environment, where permissions and resource allocations are predefined. Let me try to reproduce this issue in a docker environment and come back on this.

Comment: so far not able to reproduce this issue in Docker environment. Also older etcd version 2.4.1 doesnt have this issue. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63945714/dovecot-lmtp-error-fatal-error-failed-to-reserve-page-summary-memory  Can you please comment about minimum memory requirements for etcd?

Comment: The only requirement that I was able to find is the one above-mentioned of 8 GB. Nothing else was found, unfortunately. Did you find something?

Comment: Not w.r.t etcd. Since Patroni[raft] is lightweight, trying to use the same instead of Patroni+etcd